# Joint density of two vectors of multivariate normal random variables

Tags: probability, matrices, normal-distribution

If $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{Y}$ are dependent multivariate normal random variables, what is the joint density of $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{Y}$? Is it also multivariate normal?

Comment: On the other way round: If you know that they are independent, then they are jointly multivariate normal. If you only know they are dependent, then they are not necessary to be jointly multivariate normal in general.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the comments: In general, it is not true that $X$ and $Y$ have a jointly multivariate normal distribution. Here is one counterexample: Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y$ independent of $X$ with $P(Y=1) =1/2$ and $P(Y=-1)=1/2$. Now set $Z=XY$.

- Show that $Z$ has also normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, i.e. $Z  \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
- $X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated.
- $X$ and $Z$ are not independent. (For example $P( |X| \le t, |Z| >t) =0$, but $P(|X| \le t) P(|Z|>t) \ne 0$ for $t>0$.)